# Conferência entre listas proveniente de excel e windows

Tags: python-3.x, lista, comparação

boa tarde.
Estou desenvolvendo um programa que possui **3 etapas**:
**1ª Etapa**: Ler o um certo diretório no Windows que contém múltiplas subpastas e me retorne uma listagem com o nome de todos os arquivos que existem dentro (no caso, são nomes de fotos);
**2ª Etapa**: Ler uma planilha do excel que possui um intervalo com nome de diversas fotos;
**3º Etapa**: Resultar numa listagem de nomes de arquivos que constam no arquivo do excel (na etapa 2), mas não constam dentro do diretório do Windows (etapa 1), ou seja, a foto não existe.

A etapa1 e etapa 2 rodam, conforme abaixo

***Etapa 1***

```
pasta='C:\Users\55419\Google Drive\área de trabalho' 
caminhoAbsoluto = os.path.abspath(pasta)

for _, _, arquivo in os.walk(caminhoAbsoluto):  
    listafotos = [w.upper() for w in arquivo]
```

***Etapa 2***

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('CONFERÊNCIA DE FOTOS - teste programa.xlsx') 
sheet=wb['Planilha1'] #inserir o nome da aba a ser analisada
letracol=get_column_letter(sheet.max_column)
ultimalinha=(sheet.max_row)
maxcol=letracol+str(ultimalinha)
print(maxcol)
tuple(sheet['M1':'M440'])  #inserir o valor de maxcol encontrado
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['M1':'M440']: #inserir o valor de maxcol encontrado
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        if cellObj.value != None:
            listabase=cellObj.value
```

***Etapa 3***

```
lista_fotos_ausentes=[x for x in listabase if x not in listafotos]
print(lista_fotos_ausentes)
```

Eu não preciso que printe o resultado das etapas 1 e 2, apenas da 3. Porém, irei inserir aqui resposta das respectivas etapas para facilitar a visualização...

Etapa 1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Etapa 2
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Etapa 3
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar também o seguinte código e não adiantou

```
lista_fotos_ausentes = list(set(listabase) - set(listafotos))
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer pra que ele me retorne o nome da foto que não consta na lista de fotos? O ideal também seria que a resposta da etapa 3 ficasse em uma única coluna, como na etapa 2.

Desde já agradeço!!! =)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que entendi: a sua listabase é uma `string` e não uma lista, troque para `listabase.split("\n")` que eu acho que vai funcionar.

Comment: Oi @ArthurBacci. Eu acabei utilizando o append para adicionar cada item da iteração à minha listabase. Deu certo, todos ficaram como string dentro de uma única lista. Obrigada pelo comentário!